# powershell script to pull a list of hostnames, confirm the server is up and connect to a url with the hostname and pull something unique

Tags: powershell

Very green at PowerShell but pretty good with batch and shell scripting.  Was going to use curl but really need it to work in PowerShell and was hoping someone has an example to get me started.
I need a script to identify one of two types of IoT devices depending on web content.
I have some 20k devices that we need to identify the device to be able to manage their passwords in Cyberark and depending on which device will depend on which platform to assign it to.

I want to provide a list of hostnames in a text file, the script will confirm the host is up and responding, then connect to the host URL and pull something unique to identify which type of device and output hostname, device type A or B or hostname, NOT RESPONDING.  These IoT devices change depending on which type of battery is attached to them and we have no way of easily identifying which ones.

Comment: [1] there is a version of `curl.exe` included in windows these days. it can be called from PoSh if you use `curl.exe` instead of `curl`. ///// [2] look up >>> loops [`foreach` comes to mind]. [3] look up >>> connection testing [`get-help connection` & =`Get-Command test*connection` both look like a good places to start.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete script, but it can help you to start with..Please refer the following link for using Invoke-webrequest
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.2

```
$devices = Get-Content C:\PS\ServerNames.txt
$port = "5432" #sample port number
foreach ($device in $devices){
    $connection = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($device,$port)
    if ($connection.Connected) {
     $status = "Success"
     #$fromwebrequest = Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://yoururl" (use Invoke-webrequest instead of curl)
     
} else { 
     $status = "Not responding" 
}
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        deviceName  = $device
        Status  = $status
        devicetype = $fromwebrequest.deviceType
        #addotherparametershere
    }

}
```